# System wide symbolic link

Tags: symlink

I'm trying to create a symbolic link which would be system-wide usable.
The `$PATH` output is the follow: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games` 
So I don't understand why if I create a *sl* for example in `/bin` this *symlink* only works from inside the `/bin` directory and not from others directories.

For example:

```
# cd /bin 
# ln -s /media/bc7bc3eb-4ba9-4c12-8066-5f2e9ea747ec/SharedHOME/ ./shome
```

Comment: The symbolic Link does not understand that you want it to search $PATH, as a Symbolic Link is relative to it's parent only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$PATH` environment variable is only used when you run an executable.

In your case, you've symlinked a directory.  As a directory isn't an executable, then your shell will not search `$PATH` for it.

If you symlink to an executable, you'll find that it works as expected.